# How does one perform a Canova-Hansen test in Python?

Tags: time-series, pandas, forecasting, forecast

I am referring to the documentation [here](https://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/modules/generated/pmdarima.arima.CHTest.html#pmdarima.arima.CHTest), but it does not give many examples on how to actually perform the test. I have a pandas dataframe with two columns:

- Column 1 is first day of every week,
- Column 2 is demand, and this data goes back over 150 weeks.

How would I perform a CH test to see if there is any seasonality in my data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general this could be achieved with the snippet below where you have to replace x with your observations.

However I'm not sure whether the Caonva-Hansen-Test is suitable for weekly observations (m=52) since these sort of tests are usually designed with monthly or quarterly time series in mind.
Therefore it might be better to aggregate your observations to a monthly level (m=12).

```
from pmdarima.arima import CHTest
import numpy as np
 
x=np.random.normal(size=1000)
CHTest(m=52).estimate_seasonal_differencing_term(x)
```